# Is it possible to secure a kind with a specific credentials?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I was wondering if it is possible to secure a kind so that only a user/service-account with a specific credentials can access it.

To give an example I'm thinking to have a kind **user**, that is going to be used across different envrionments under the same project.

What I was thinkinig of doing is having:

- user-dev - used only on dev environment with dev credentials
- user-uat - used only on uat environment with uat credentials
- user-prod - used only on prod envrioment with prod credentials

If it is not possible what are the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to Sebastien solution is to create a separate projects in google could console for each entity.

A little bit more configuration but gives you a better security model without creating addition layers.

In my example I have created projects:

- project_name-dev-storage + entity + service account
- project_name-uat-storage + entity + service account
- project_name-prod-storage + entity + service account

Answer (score 0):

The alternative would be to save the Entity User under different namespaces. In your case you would then have 3 namespaces:

- com.yoursite.dev
- com.yoursite.uat
- com.yoursite.prod

You then instantiate the Datastore with the corresponding namespace (taken from environment var) according to the environment the application is deployed.

Comment: I was looking into it but I couldn't find any option which would allow to secure namespaces so that the dev doesn't have access to any namespace except it self and so on. Do you know if that is possible?

Comment: The namespace could be complex and not "guessable" but I don't think you can prevent a developer to write an Entity to any other namespace without some kind of api layer.

Comment: Looking in more details couldn't find any way except creating a separate projects: *-dev-storage, *-uat-storage etc and creating service accounts for each one. Different why of handling access right, I would prefer to be able to secure based on entity and service account but for time being separate project will have to do the magic.